# Visiblity issue with Checkbox- Android

Tags: android, checkbox, visibility

I have two set of codes in my activity ,

one is for->
Saving Checkbox State even after app exits & also enable checkboxes by default

And the Other One is for->
Calling visibility if the specified checkbox is checked and make my Progressbar visible according to the checkboxes

i have 5 checkboxes, 2 progressbars in my Layout

Problem- only One set of code works properly, if i use both, the checkboxes behave weird, they don't check by default, they don't save and progressbars don't change state

Java

```
package com.example.myapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Settings extends Activity {

CheckBox checkBox_one  = null;
CheckBox checkBox_two = null;
CheckBox checkBox_three = null;
CheckBox checkBox_four = null;
CheckBox checkBox_five = null;    
ProgressBar progressBar1;
ProgressBar progressBar2;

CheckBox checkBox_1 ;
CheckBox checkBox_2 ;
CheckBox checkBox_3 ;
CheckBox checkBox_4 ;
CheckBox checkBox_5 ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);  

    progressBar1 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    progressBar2 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);

      checkBox_one = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
      checkBox_one.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked) {
            updateProgressBars();
        }
      });

      checkBox_two = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
      checkBox_two.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked) {
            updateProgressBars();
        }
      });


    }    


public void updateProgressBars() {

   progressBar1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
   progressBar2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

   if (checkBox_one.isChecked() && checkBox_two.isChecked()) {
      progressBar2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   } else if (checkBox_one.isChecked()) {
      progressBar1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   }

  //SAVE CHECKBOX STATE//

checkBox_1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

boolean isChecked = getBooleanFromPreferences("isChecked");
Log.i("start",""+isChecked);
checkBox_1.setChecked(isChecked);
checkBox_1.setChecked(true);//Enable By Default
checkBox_1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

  @Override
  public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked) {
      Log.i("boolean",""+isChecked);
      Settings.this.putBooleanInPreferences(isChecked,"isChecked");
  }
});

checkBox_2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);

boolean isCheckedTwo = getBooleanFromPreferences("isCheckedTwo");
checkBox_2.setChecked(isCheckedTwo );
checkBox_2.setChecked(true);//Enable By Default
checkBox_2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked) {

      Settings.this.putBooleanInPreferences(isChecked,"isCheckedTwo");
  }
});

checkBox_3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);

boolean isCheckedThree = getBooleanFromPreferences("isCheckedThree");
checkBox_3.setChecked(isCheckedThree );
checkBox_3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked) {

      Settings.this.putBooleanInPreferences(isChecked,"isCheckedThree");
  }
});

checkBox_4 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);

boolean isCheckedFour = getBooleanFromPreferences("isCheckedFour");
checkBox_4.setChecked(isCheckedFour );
checkBox_4.setChecked(true);//Enable By Default
checkBox_4.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked) {

      Settings.this.putBooleanInPreferences(isChecked,"isCheckedFour");
  }
});

checkBox_5 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox5);

boolean isCheckedFive = getBooleanFromPreferences("isCheckedFive");
checkBox_5.setChecked(isCheckedFive );
checkBox_5.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked) {

      Settings.this.putBooleanInPreferences(isChecked,"isCheckedFive");
      }
     });

   }

  public void putBooleanInPreferences(boolean isChecked,String key){
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
  editor.putBoolean(key, isChecked);
  editor.commit();        
  }
  public boolean getBooleanFromPreferences(String key){
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
  Boolean isChecked = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, false);
   return isChecked;       

 }
  //-------------------------//


@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    // Stop back button Functioning
}

public void openrate1(View view) { 
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Rate.class);
startActivity(intent);
}

public void gotohome(View view) { 
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
}

public void savesettings(View view) { 
    Toast toast=Toast.makeText(this, "Settings successfully saved!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG); 
    toast.show();   
    }                        


}
```

XML

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
    android:text="checkBox1"
    android:textColor="#585858"
    android:textSize="18dp" />


<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:text="checkBox2"
    android:textColor="#585858"
    android:textSize="18dp" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox2"
    android:text="checkBox3"
    android:textColor="#585858"
    android:textSize="18dp" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox3"
    android:text="checkBox4"
    android:textColor="#585858"
    android:textSize="18dp" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox4"
    android:text="checkBox5"
    android:textColor="#585858"
    android:textSize="18dp" /> 



 <ProgressBar
       android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
       style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="40dp"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
       android:progress="20"

       />

   <ProgressBar
       android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
       style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="40dp"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignTop="@+id/progressBar1"
       android:progress="40" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, but seeing the same listener 5 times, I suggest creating just the one and use for instance getResourceEntryName as key.

Comment: I'm just curious to know the purpose of setting the CheckBox values  twice( checkBox_1.setChecked(isChecked);checkBox_1.setChecked(true))

Comment: @RegisteredUser Consider you have unchecked checkBox_1 during first run and saved the value for isChecked=false in SharedPreferences, then what happens with these lines checkBox_1.setChecked(isChecked);checkBox_1.setChecked(true) when you restart the app ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is confusing and it doesn't help that it isn't indented very well. However, there is something fundamentally wrong here. You do this

```
checkBox_one = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
```

then later do this

```
checkBox_1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
```

they are referencing the same `View` in your layout but whatever you do to one won't effect the other one. Just initialize it once then use that instance (`checkBox_one`) everywhere that you need to reference that `CheckBox`.

Answer (score 0):

When `checkBox1` or `checkBox2` change of state, the `updateProgressBars` re-set all checkbox to true.

And why doing that?

```
checkBox_1.setChecked(isChecked);
checkBox_1.setChecked(true);
```

Comment: yes, but setChecked(true) is called at EVERY click on checkBox1 or checkBox2

Answer (score 0):

@RegisteredUser I have made some changes to your code for saving and retrieving the Checkbox states from SharedPreferences. I have not included ProgressBar part, Please work on it.

```
public class Settings extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener {

    CheckBox checkBox_one = null;
    CheckBox checkBox_two = null;
    CheckBox checkBox_three = null;
    CheckBox checkBox_four = null;
    CheckBox checkBox_five = null;
    CheckBox checkBoxArray[];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    checkBox_one = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    checkBox_two = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
    checkBox_three = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
    checkBox_four = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);
    checkBox_five = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox5);

    checkBox_one.setTag("isChecked");
    checkBox_two.setTag("isCheckedTwo");
    checkBox_three.setTag("isCheckedThree");
    checkBox_four.setTag("isCheckedFour");
    checkBox_five.setTag("isCheckedFive");

    // Set Checked states based on preferences and register
    // OnCheckedChangelisteners.
    checkBoxArray = new CheckBox[] { checkBox_one, checkBox_two,
        checkBox_three, checkBox_four, checkBox_five };
    for (CheckBox checkBox : checkBoxArray) {
        boolean mState = getBooleanFromPreferences(checkBox.getTag()
            .toString());
        checkBox.setChecked(mState);
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    }    
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    putBooleanInPreferences(isChecked, buttonView.getTag().toString());
    }

    public void putBooleanInPreferences(boolean isChecked, String key) {
    Log.d("Sharedpreference", key + " : " + isChecked);
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this
        .getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(key, isChecked);
    editor.commit();
    }

    public boolean getBooleanFromPreferences(String key) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this
        .getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Boolean isChecked = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, true);
    return isChecked;
    }
```

Comment: @RegisteredUser I guess you haven't changed the layout name use setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings); And if any error please paste the Logcat output.

Comment: ofcourse i have changed it and can you please run the original code provided in question in your IDE? because i want both sets of code working properly